# Invoke Lambda from CloudFormation template or vice-versa

Tags: python, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Sometimes I need certain fields in a CF template to be dynamically generated from a list of complex objects, currently I don't know of any way to loop over anything using CF functions so parts of the execution is delegated to Lambdas -- by providing the list of parameters as character-delimited strings -- which in turn use the Python/Ruby AWS SDK to create other resources.

It seems to me that it would be easier to invoke a Lambda first, that Lambda would dynamically construct the CF stack given an arbitrarily complex JSON payload without having to encode list of objects as character-delimited strings.

This seems like inverting the current pattern I have where the CF template invokes Lambdas and instead have a Lambda receive the parameters and then create the CF stack using Python/Ruby SDK (as part of the Lambda execution).

I haven't found much about this pattern being a bad idea or it being discouraged but I also haven't found many examples of it on the web.

Btw, I'm quite new to CF and Lambdas so I'm not sure if this is a no-no for AWS/CF/Lambdas, so this question is partly to figure that out.

## Example

Creating an ECS task definition with a dynamic list of port mappings:

```
"ecsTask":{
      "Properties":{
        # ... other stuffs
        "container_definitions": [
          {
            "name": {"Ref":"AWS::StackName"},
            "image": {"Ref":"DockerImage"},
            "portMappings": [
                # ... dynamic list of ports, example below
                {
                    "ContainerPort": "123",
                    "HostPort": "456"
                },
            ],
            "environment":{ "Ref": "EnvironmentVariables" },
          # ... other stuffs
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: Sounds like a deploy-time thing, not an execution-time thing. So, lambda would not be a good choice for this.

Comment: Hello. Could you give an example of a resource you build dynamically based on logic too complicated for CF functions?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil It's not even that complicated, that's why I think there must be a simpler solution.

Comment: After reading a bit more I found some related ideas, to overcome this limitation of CF templates some people use other template languages like ERB or Jinja2 to generate the body of the CF template: http://priocept.com/2017/07/18/taming-cloudformation-with-yaml-and-jinja2-templating-part-1/